# How long will restic wait before exiting with an error if the files I try to back up are not available?

Tags: connection, backup

I have a restic repository for the backup of some data. I access the data over ethernet, since it is not physically stored on the same computer on which restic runs.
I know that if restic looses access to the repository, it immediately exits with an error; but what if I loose access to the files I'm trying to back up ?